# "Group" vs. "community" usage

Tags: meaning, word-choice, meaning-in-context, nouns

#### Question 1

When we have a certain number of people that share the same interest, do we refer to **them** as:

1. interest **group** or
2. **community** [sharing same interest]?

What would be preferred and more correct? Maybe there's a third option that would be even more appropriate for this context?

#### Question 2

The word *group* by itself can be associated with anything — people, things, etc. *Community*, on the other hand (as far as I know), is generally associated with people, right?

#### Question 3

When we use the term *group*, does it already imply a certain size or not? Is the word *group* used more frequently with smaller numbers or can a group's size be any number larger than two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, when we say **community**, we refer to a large number of people or entities, who may be affiliated to many smaller or disparate sub-structures.Community almost always refers to a varied and large audience, yet with certain things, which maybe certain interests, opinions, or religion or ethnicity.

On the other hand, **group** is indeed most often used for a small number of people or other entities, each of which may or may not be large. Also, a group is not as natural a collection as community. A group maybe formed by some of us just now, but a community arises on its own and comes together, and has more naturally common attributes. Similarly, one can be expelled from a group, if he disrespects the rules, but one cannot be banned from a community per se, unless it is something very artificial like a virtual social networking aggregate that is moderated etc.

E.g. we talk about the international community of researchers of a certain field, say Physics, or the international community of institutional investors (each of which is an institution like a bank and consists of millions of people), whereas we say G8- a group of nations.

Comment: That's about Q3, then.

Comment: Dictionaries do not seem to indicate any size connotations for either of the words.

Comment: well, u already answered Q1 when I saw, and Q2. could be left as an exercise. So. :)

Comment: :) Sorry, I took too long to post the answer(s), feeling sleepy today.

Comment: Dictionaries may not always comment on usage. Would you like to call a  group of 3 a community? or, a 200 people among 300 a group?

Comment: Amazon.com: CLAUDETTE COLBERT in "A Community of Two..." http://www.amazon.com/CLAUDETTE-COLBERT-Community-Jerome-Chodorov/dp/B005LS9FI4  --  I have not read this.

Comment: "SPOTTED: Massive groups of prospies on tours" http://spectrum.columbiaspectator.com/spectrum/spotted-massive-groups-of-prospies-on-tours

Comment: nor have i! is there a meaning that doesnt meet the eye?

Comment: 'massive' groups. these couldnt have communities though. maybe gatherings..but there is a bias.

Comment: Thanks for the general view of each of these terms in regards to their size. But all other things that you've written is interesting as well. I wasn't thinking of group/community membership at all untill you mentioned it. this site for instance is a **community of people interested in English language**. It's not a group of people I would deduct from your answer. Right? I suppose yes. Even though this site has all the properties of group membership that you mentioned. :) You can be banned from this site, but not from your own interest...

Comment: Could we also say that one *is a member* of a group, but *belongs* to a community? Does it matter at all?

Comment: @Robert Koritnik: Google books has over 18K instances of ["I belong to a group"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I+belong+to+a+group%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) - four times as many as "I belong to a community". Mainly because "group" is a more common word in the first place. There's no special reason for either to associate more strongly with "belonging".

Comment: @FumbleFingers: but that's just an assumption based on Google Books search. It's not a fact, is it?

Comment: @Robert Koritnik: Not sure what you mean by "fact". Obviously *group* *is* more common, and it has wider "reach" than *community*. GB has 786 instances of ["belongs to a group of elements"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22belongs+to+a+group+of+elements%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), for example - but unsurprisingly, not a single one for *"belongs to a community of elements"*. So there are definitely some contexts where *belong* and *community* aren't a good pairing, but *belong* and *group* are. Is that the kind of "fact" you want?

Comment: ...you might also like to note that GB has over 1000K instances of *"special interest group"*, but only 31K for *"special interest community"*. As @Kris says, *community* is something of a "buzzword" these days (everyone is trying to cash in on the *online community*), but it's not likely to actually displace "group" in most contexts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I suppose the odd combination is not *belong & community* but rather *community & elements*...

Comment: @RobertKoritnik Yes, "You can be banned from this site, but not from your own interest..".. thats what I meant. :) and yes, we are a community, not a group.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I would like to give a 'counting' argument for a change. :) Given, the fact that groups are generally small, there are a large number of them, whereas, since communities are large, there cannot be too many of them. Hence more mention of groups as they are described. :D Yes, given the exponential spread of social networking forums, the number of so-called virtual communities have gone up like anything, hence the citation. I should also point out 'group' is a basic structure in abstract algebra, which also may have blown it up. :)

Comment: Yes - if I said anything suggesting *group* and *community* are "equal" I didn't mean to. I think you're right that all other things being equal, one would tend to think *communities* are larger than *groups* (and may in fact even contain them, which doesn't seem so natural the other way around).

Answer (score 2):

***community*** or ***interest group***.

Not *interest community*.

Essentially, *group* is a non-specific collection while *community* has a commonality among its members. That is the reason *group* requires the adjective 'interest' and *community* does not.

You could think of a community as a group defined by locale/ common interest/ feature/ ancestry, etc. Btw, *community* is currently the buzzword.

---

**Q2** Neither *group* nor *community* is necessarily associated with people as such. However, *community*  is generally applicable to animate objects only, *group* to 'things' of all descriptions.

---

**Q3** While *group* by itself does not have connotations of a small size, we have other words to refer to collections to suggest a large size, so that we do not usually see *group* used for large collections.

Comment: AD3: Which *other* words would that be? Can you edit your answer and add a few examples?

Comment: @Robert Koritnik: To quote Arlo Guthrie's [Alice's Restaurant](http://www.arlo.net/resources/lyrics/alices.shtml) a bigger group can be an *organization* - and if it's really big - *"friends, they may think it's a **movement**"*

Comment: Kris, I suggest you add *locale* to "interest/ feature/ ancestry" list, and expand *Btw*. Note, "community is currently the buzzword" is content-free unless you say in what context.

Answer (score 1):

One aspect is not just size, but strength of relation.  When I hear community, I think either a natural occurring community of people who live near each other, or an intentional community of people who share many beliefs about how they want to live their lives, rather than a group having only a singular interest in common. Thus, the nuns who live down the road from me, though only numbering 8, is a community, and my town, which numbers in the thousands, is a community, whereas to me ELU is a group.  Certainly, there are occasions when both could be used, and there some where neither would apply;  I wouldn't call my church congregation either term.

Comment: "to me ELU is a group" -- why might it be so, any thoughts?

Comment: just as you say: "To me..." makes this answer rather subjective doesn't it? I was much more after grammatical correctness.

Comment: Yes, I agree I was being subjective.  Either is grammatically correct.  I would use them differently, though, and I thought that was what you were after.

Answer (score 1):

[SIG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_Interest_Group) - Special Interest Group is common.

Just to add to the befuddlement, there is also [neighborship](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/neighborship).

Answer (score 0):

members of a group know each other, whether it is a small or large group. but it is not so in case of community.

Comment: Could you, please, post any references to back up your claim.